# SharePoint Online workflow IPaddresses

Tags: sharepoint, office365, workflowservice

I am using SharePoint online in the US region. There is an option in a custom 2013 workflow to send an HTTP request. For firewall purposes, what are the IP addresses that SharePoint online uses for outgoing http requests from workflows?

Answer (score 1):

The IP will depend on the region and server cluster. The admin section of SP Online will not provide that information - mine does not. To find out your IP, you will have to create a test server and the connections logs. A simple apache or Nginx will go.

Comment: how many different IP's should I expect these requests to come from... so far there's only been one.

Comment: Only one. It would be wasteful to have multiple public IPs assigned to an instance.

Comment: does that mean if I make another workflow the IP could be different?

Comment: They should be the same IP. That said, the  FW admin can allow a full set of IP ranges.